# Calling stored procedure in select statement with Db2

Tags: db2, db2-400

I have a select statement that's working fine but I need one more value that comes from a stored procedure and I can't call it as a value in the select statement

```
select 
    recp.percent,
    (call libraryEXT.get_rate_for_detail(detail_number))
from 
    mainTable.orders ORD
inner join 
    mainTable.receipts recp on ORD.rcptID = recp.rcptID
```

It works fine to only get recp.percent, but putting the next value in for calling the stored procedure says it doesn't expect "call"

If I run the stored procedure by itself it returns one record with the columns: `name, rcptID, time` and I need the rcptID from that

How can I properly call the stored procedure and make the value returned be my other value in the select statment?

Comment: You cannot do this in a singe query, but you can instead use a compound SQL block with multiple statements to achieve what you need.

Comment: @mao what do you mean by compound block, exactly?

Comment: Either an anonymous block, or a named block (e.g. another sproc).  For the former, study the docs https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcompounddynstmt.htm

Comment: Actually, you should be able to wrap a CALL statement into a table function if you want, if your SP doesn't use some not supported actions inside. [CREATE FUNCTION (SQL table)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcftb.htm). [SQL control statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzsqlcontstmts.htm) of such a function may contain a CALL statement.

Answer (score 0):

As @mao said,  this is not possible to call an SP in a select statement.

If you are the SP owner,  try creating a table-function instead. This one can be called in a select statement.

Comment: given the way the call is being used, which apparently a single value being returned...a scalar function is a better choice.

Comment: @charles,  he mention in his question that his SP returns 1 row, with 3 columns

Comment: Samuel, I didn't see that... Otoh... He only needs the one value out of the three... So a scalar  UDF is still a valid solution

Answer (score 0):

Given the way you've used `CALL libraryEXT.get_rate_for_detail(detail_number)` it's apparently only returning a single value.

That being the case, you'd be better served by having it as a scaler User Defined Function (UDF).

Then this is what your code would look like:

```
select 
    recp.percent,
    libraryEXT.get_rate_for_detail_UDF(detail_number) as rate
from 
    mainTable.orders ORD
inner join 
    mainTable.receipts recp on ORD.rcptID = recp.rcptID
```

I renamed the function just to be clear it's NOT the stored proc.  If you created the stored proc, you could delete it and use the same name for the UDF.